# How to strip comma in Python string

Tags: python, string, strip

How can I strip the comma from a Python string such as `Foo, bar`? I tried `'Foo, bar'.strip(',')`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You want to [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) it, not [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) it:

```
s = s.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: @jamylak `s = re.sub(',','', s)` ;)

Answer (score 20):

Use `replace` method of strings not `strip`:

```
s = s.replace(',','')
```

An example:

```
>>> s = 'Foo, bar'
>>> s.replace(',',' ')
'Foo  bar'
>>> s.replace(',','')
'Foo bar'
>>> s.strip(',') # clears the ','s at the start and end of the string which there are none
'Foo, bar'
>>> s.strip(',') == s
True
```

Comment: Man! It's so obvious! SO OBVIOUS! But so obvious that I was using strip and trying to understand why it didn't work as a bulk replace...

Answer (score 7):

`unicode('foo,bar').translate(dict([[ord(char), u''] for char in u',']))`

Comment: +2 for being a one-liner in addition to overall ridiculousness

Answer (score 1):

This will strip all commas from the text and left justify it.

```
for row in inputfile:
    place = row['your_row_number_here'].strip(', ')
```

‎
‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎